# How to return a status code in a Lagom Service call

Tags: java, lagom

I want to implement a typical rest POST call in Lagom. The POST creates an object, and returns it, with a status code of 201.

However, the default return code is 200. It is possible to set a status code, as shown here (https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ServiceImplementation.html#Handling-headers).

However, I cannot figure out how to do it for a more complicated case. My create is asynchronious, and I return an object instead of a String.

This is the code I have:

```
    @Override
public HeaderServiceCall<OrderRequest.CreateOrderRequest, Order> createOrder() {
    UUID orderId = UUID.randomUUID();
    ResponseHeader responseHeader = ResponseHeader.OK.withStatus(201);

    return (requestHeader, request) -> {
        CompletionStage<Order> stage = registry.refFor(OrderEntity.class, orderId.toString())
                .ask(buildCreateOrder(orderId, request))
                .thenApply(reply -> toApi(reply));

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Pair.create(responseHeader, stage.toCompletableFuture()));
    };
}
```

However, the return value should be `Pair<ResponseHeader, Order>`, not `Pair<ResponseHeader, CompletionStage<Order>>` which I have now, so it does not compile.

I could of course extract the Order myself, by putting the completionStage into an CompletableFuture and getting that, but that would make the call synchronous and force me to deal with InterruptExceptions etc, which seems a bit complex for something that should be trivial.

What is the correct way to set a status code in Lagom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it solved. Instead of creating a new `completedFuture` you could compose `stage` with a lambda that builds the final `Pair` like this:

```
return stage.thenApply( order -> Pair.create(responseHeader, order));
```

And putting all the pieces together:

```
registry.refFor(OrderEntity.class, orderId.toString())
            .ask(buildCreateOrder(orderId, request))
            .thenApply( reply -> toApi(reply)); 
            .thenApply( order -> Pair.create(responseHeader, order));
```